# How will Chebychev inequality look like incase of a p-norm.

Tags: analysis, definition

If I have this as a given:

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty }\int_{E} |f_{n} - f|^p = 0.$$

And I want to use  Chebychev inequality to show convergence in measure of $\{f_{n}\}.$ How will Chebychev inequality look like? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\epsilon^{p}|(|f_{n}-f|\geq\epsilon)|\leq\int|f_{n}-f|^{p}\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
|(|f_{n}-f|\geq\epsilon)|\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: why you have $\epsilon ^p$? on pg 80 in Royden(4th edition) it does not contain a power of p

Comment: The point is that, $|f_{n}-f|\geq\epsilon$ implies $|f_{n}-f|^{p}\geq\epsilon^{p}$, and this fits with the integrand which is $|f_{n}-f|^{p}$, and you need to use Chebychev in accord with the integrand.

Comment: what about the power of $\epsilon$ inside the parentheses on the LHS why it remained 1?

Comment: Note that $|f_{n}-f|\geq\epsilon$ is equivalent to $|f_{n}-f|^{p}\geq\epsilon^{p}$.

Comment: So inside the parentheses I can put $|f_{n} - f |^p \geq \epsilon ^p$ instead?

Comment: Yes of course you can.